# How to join two tables in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, join, where

I need some help i have a query, struggling to use join and database is sql server. Below is my table definition.

```
// sql server query
SELECT TOP 1000 [Station Code]
      ,[Transaction Code]
      
  FROM [Tracking_Server_DB].[dbo].[TS_Station]
  where [Station Description] = 'R600'
  order by [Tracking Client Name] desc


SELECT
      ,[Transaction Code]
      ,[DateTime Passed]
      
  FROM [Tracking_Server_DB].[dbo].[Checkpoint Movement]
```

Comment: Maybe `select top 1000 tss.station_code, test.transaction_code, cm.transaction_code, cm.dt_passed from ts_station ts join checkpoint_movement cm on ts.transaction_code =  cm.transaction_code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Below is my table definition* Nope - "below" are 2 queries you wrote. Don't make things worse by mis-using terminology.

This seems relatively straightforward but that is a rather significant guess based solely on column names. A simple join would be:

```
select ...
from dbo.TS_Station as stn
inner join dbo.[Checkpoint Movement] as mv 
   on stn.[Transaction Code] = mv.[Transaction Code]
where stn.[Station Description] = 'R600'
order by ...;
```

Notice I removed the database name. Don't use 3-part names with a very good reason. Your connection should determine the database to use. Also I remove the square brackets from names that do not need them. Make life easier by making your code easier to read. For that matter, use names that follow the rules for regular identifiers so that you don't need to use delimiters. A name with spaces will simply require more work from you.

I have no idea if that join makes logical sense and meets your (as yet unwritten) needs. I suspect the join logic is more complicated, but this seems like a starting point.

Comment: the idea i want to achieve. I want to write one query that will filter all the checkpoints by using join, i notice we got two tables from the same database(Tracking Server Database) One table(Station) and other Checkpoint_Movement.

Comment: The result of a query **is** a table! Plus 1 for the good advice!